# Visual Studio 6 Loop Displaying

Tags: loops, vb6

How do I display the following:

```
Q1)1    Q2)1AAAA
   00      12BBB
   111     123CC
   0000    1234D
   11111
```

Comment: Is this homework?  Why would displaying the following require a loop anwyay?  If you want help you need to explain your question in more detail

Comment: You may want to add more information so your question does not get closed

Answer (score 1):

```
MessageBox.Show("Q1)1 Q2)1AAAA 00 12BBB 111 123CC 0000 1234D 11111")
```

Please explain what you need the loop(s) to do. Also please show your code so far so we can help.

**EDIT**

Ok the various output lines make more sense now in your question. However it would still be useful and recommended to post your code thus far, so we can help point you in the right direction.

(Glad to help but aren't here to write everything for you.)

Comment: You mean MessageBox.Show("Q1)1 Q2)1AAAA 00 12BBB 111 123CC 0000 1234D 11111") as he wants VB.NET not C# :)

Comment: Ah, true indeed. Thanks I will edit it accordingly!

Comment: Won't work alas, the initial formatting was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Q1:

- make an outer loop from 1 to 5 (i).
- make an inner loop from 1 to i (j).
- if i is odd, add 1 else 0 to a string and write it at the end of the inner loop. (and clear it).

Q2:

- make an outer loop from 1 to 4 (i).
- make an inner loop from 1 to i (j).
- add the number j to a temp string.
- add 5-i times the character X(i) where X(1) = A, X(2) = B etc.
- print and clear the string before the next iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code only, since this smells suspiciously like homework :-)

Number 1:

```
string s1, s2         or shifty version:  string s
integer i, j                              integer i,j,k
s1 = "1"                                  k = 0
for i = 1 to 5                            for i = 1 to 5
    s2 = ""                                   s = ""
    for j = 1 to i                            for j = 1 to i
        s2 = s2 + s1                              s = s + chr(k+30)
    endfor                                    endfor
    output s2                                 output s
    if s1 = "1" then                          k = 1 - k
        s1 = "0"                          endfor
    else
        s1 = "1"
    endif
endfor
```

Number 2:

```
string s
integer i, j
for i = 1 to 4
    s = ""
    for j = 1 to i
        s = s + chr(j+30)
    endfor
    for j = i+1 to 5
        s = s + chr(i+64)
    endfor
    output s
endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for inner and outer loop. This will do it:
Q1:

```
    For p As Integer = 1 To 5
        MsgBox("".PadRight(p, CChar((p Mod 2).ToString)))
    Next
```

Q2:

```
    Dim pre As String = ""
    For p As Integer = 0 To 3
        pre &= (p + 1).ToString
        MsgBox(pre & "".PadRight(4 - p, CChar(Chr(65 + p))))
    Next
```

PS. Please tell us your teachers reaction to "your" solution. ;)